# Free memory atomically

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads

This is a function, I am using to free dynamically allocated memory

```
void Free(void* arg) {
    if(arg!=NULL) {
        free(arg);
        arg=NULL;
    }
}
```

So far it was working fine, until I started using pthreads. From time to time my stack is being smashed, and the only thing I can do is to use pthread_mutex_lock()

Is there any atomic bulletin to check&free memory in gcc?
Or may be you can present another solution? I hope that mutex is not the only way to do that

Comment: What OS?  On Linux, `malloc` and `free` use mutexes internally.

Comment: You should read the documentation of `free`. It handles `NULL` itself very well. And since all you modify is only a local variable by setting it to NULL... this is quite a pointless function, to be honest.

Comment: Threads share an address space... so you can only free memory from one thread. Once memory is `free()`'d there is no way to determine if it was once valid memory - it could be re-used...

Comment: Linux. Let's say, the first thread just went through if condition, and the second one just freed the memory. does the first thread crash?

Comment: @ArtEm just don't call free() on the same malloced pointer more than once.  It doesn't matter if the duplicate free() is from the same thread that malloced it or not - it's still wrong, and you'll still get an exception raised.  If you want to pass/signal dynamically-allocated blocks to multiple threads in such a way that the threads assume ownership of them, malloc a new block for each thread.

Comment: Usually people have this construct as a macro like SAFE_DELETE/SAFE_RELEASE/SAFE_FREE

Comment: If you want to mallocate a block, have all threads use the same block, then have all the threads 'free' the block when done, then a) don't do that,  b) Use a mutex-protected reference-count.  c) don't do that unless you have absolutely no way whatsoever of avoiding it by a redesign.

Comment: I mean, as an example. if I had some config data in a malloced block that needs to be read by all threads, is never written by them, and can happily last until the end of the process run, I would probably just not bother explicitly freeing it at all.

Comment: @MartinJames And of course you can *allocate* and *free* such block in the main thread of the program instead. I think the main issue here is design too. There should be clear ownership of the block of memory. If it's meant to be shared accross threads then it belongs to the program, and should only be `free()`ed after the main program is certain that all threads have finished executing.

Comment: Why do you "*hope that mutexes are not the only way*", if there is the need to access the data simultaneoulsy then a simple way to do it is by using mutexes, and depending on certain things it's a perfectly acceptable solution. But perhaps, there are some of those "*certain things*" that worry you, right?

Comment: Mutexes aren't the only way, what you appear to be asking can be done through compare-and-swap atomic operation. On the other hand your design looks very strange. If one thread frees block (safely), other threads won't be able to use it, that's a possible race condition. As others commented try freeing memory in main thread after all threads are done. Or describe your design in more detail (how many threads and what they do).

Comment: So your question is, basically "I am using `free` to free allocated memory from multiple threads simultaneously, and it doesn't work, but I don't want to lock"? You don't need an OS mutex for pthreads, just use a spinlock if you're concerned about performance.

Comment: By the way, `arg=NULL;` doesn't do anything. You're just modifying the local variable which is never used again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `malloc` and `free` functions use mutexes internally to ensure that heap is managed properly.  This does not however protect against your application attempting to read/write a variable from more than one thread.

Anytime a variable that two or more threads have access to is read or written, you need to protect that access with a mutex.  Otherwise you end up with inconsistent states and you can't predict your program's behavior.

On a side note, your function as written won't set the pointer passed in to NULL.  What it's doing is setting a local variable to NULL, which is not visible to the calling function.  For this to work, it would need to accept a `void **`:

```
void Free(void **arg) {
    if(arg!=NULL) {
        free(*arg);
        *arg=NULL;
    }
}
```

And be called like this:

```
Free((void **)&ptr);
```

This is one of those cases where using a macro is actually cleaner:

```
#define Free(arg) do { free(arg); (arg) = NULL; } while (0)
```

Comment: Or better `void *p = *arg; *arg = NULL; free(p);`

Comment: Well, if it's config data that is never written by the threads concerned, there's no point in locking it.

Comment: @Rarity just design to avoid that issue ever cropping up.  If it can never happen, you don't need to find inventive ways of making it safe that may, or may not work reliably:)